# colorbox get's fired even the condition is false jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I use the following function to check on a certain condition so that the color box plugin will not get fired unless the condition is true!

```
function settleCashInterface(){
    var element;
    $('#bill-list').find(".bill-item-list").each(function (){
          if($(this).css("display") == "block"){
            element = $(this);
            return false;
          }else{
              element = 0;
          }
        });
    if(element != 0){
        $(".settle-cash").colorbox({inline:true, width:"72%"});
        var data = "billId=" + element.parent().attr("id") + "&settlementType=No";
        ajaxCall("/setlement","POST",data,function(response){
            $('#settle-cash').find('.table-number').val(response.settleInfo.tableNo);
            $('#settle-cash').find('.room').val(element.parent().find('.room-number').html());
            $('#settle-cash').find('.num-of-guests').val("3"); //hard coded values
            $('#settle-cash').find('.total').val(response.settleInfo.totalAmout);
            $('#settle-cash').find('.total-due').val(response.settleInfo.totalAmout);
            $('#settle-cash').find('.total-due').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#settle-cash').find('.final-value').html(response.settleInfo.totalAmout);
            $('#settle-cash').attr("billId",element.parent().attr("id"));
            $('#settle-cash').attr("billNo",element.parent().find('.bill-number').html());
        });
        resetAddBill();
    }else{
        alert("Select a bill");
    }
}
```

The function is triggers on the click event and the following code!

```
$('.settle-cash').click(function(){
        settleCashInterface();
    });
```

The color box should run if an element is displayed and if not, it shouldn't. When I click on the respective element, this shows a message if there is no element with display block css style. I used firebug to debug. when I first click the condition gets fired perfectly and the colorbox will not show! but when I make an element show and make it hide, the condition gets fired and a alert displays! when I close the alert box, the colorbox gets fired! how can I stop this!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Make sure your elements are set to anything other than block. So `display: none` etc because block is the default value.